# Rails: apply where conditions to both model and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, where-clause

in my app I have the models Item, Category and Categorization defined as above:

```
    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :description, :property_valuations, :barcode

      has_many :categorizations
      has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
    end

    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :description, :parent, :children, :items, :parent_id

      has_many :children, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :nullify
      belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"

      has_many :categorizations
      has_many :items, :through => :categorizations

      def all_children(children_array = [])
        children = Category.where(:parent_id => self.id).includes(:items)

        children_array += children.all
        children.each do |child|      
          children_array = child.all_children(children_array)
        end
        children_array
      end

    end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :item

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :item

end
```

I'm search the category tree recursively for items associated to categories. However, besides filtering categories by parent_id, I want to apply a filter items name. How can I do this (I was expecting something like `Category.where(:parent_id => self.id).includes(:items).where(:name => 'something...')`)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Category.where(:parent_id => self.id).includes(:items).where("items.name like ?", '%cheap%')
```

---

That will get the categories, and the items that matched the criteria.

i.e.:

```
categories = Category.where(:parent_id => 2).includes(:items).where("items.name like ?", 'AA%')
categories.first.items.size # -> 2
categories.first.id # -> 1
Category.find(1).items.size # -> 3
Category.find(1).items.where("name like ?", 'AA%').count # -> 2
```

---

If you just want to get the items of the subcategories of a parent category:

```
parent_category = Category.find(2)
Item.joins(:categories).where(categories: {parent_id: parent_category.id}).where("items.name like ?", 'AA%')
```

Comment: Doesn't that only get items associated with categories that are direct children of the selected category?

Comment: That gets the categories associated with the items you are looking for, and when you check the items of each category, it only gets the items that matched the criteria.
What's the result you want to get? Its not clear (at least for me) on the question.

Comment: Assuming you want to check all the id's from your all_children, if you make an array all_children_ids then you can find(all_children_ids) and that will lead to an efficient 'Find xx in' sql instead of repeated queries if you hit the id's individually.

Comment: He wrote the code for his models and the problem he has, if you have a better way to query the day, why don't you write the proposed code on a different answer? He explained he wanted to get all the items, not just the id.

Comment: He also clearly wants the items associated with all descendent categories from the chosen top category.  To do that with your answer by changing from find(one_id) to find(all_ids_array) seems like such a tiny edit it would be silly to pretend it's another answer.

Comment: no its not, you can edit your answer and add the code, it will be helpful for others checking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive querying (to avoid the manual recursion of your all_children function) might be supported by your database, eg postgres via the with command, but rails doesn't have a wrapper that accesses that.  If that recursion happens a lot, it might be worth doing some reading here: http://gmarik.info/blog/2012/10/14/recursive-data-structures-with-rails -- and it does look there are some promising gems addressing the issue, but I haven't used any of them personally.